# UICollectionView reloadData resigns first responder/dismisses keyboard when searchBar is in section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I have a `UICollectionView` that have section header. In the section header I have a `UISearchBar`. I want to filter the content in my collection view when I type in the search bar. I do this with the following method:

```
// The method to change the predicate of the FRC
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
    NSString *query = searchText;
    if (query && query.length) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@ or createdAt contains[cd] %@ or noteText contains[cd] %@ or keywords contains[cd] %@", query, query, query, query];
        [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    } else {
        [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:nil];
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

This method gets called every time the search bar text changes. The line `[self.collectionView reloadData]` hided the keyboard for every character. Is it possible to reload only the data in a UICollection view and not reload the Supplementary views like section headers headers?

The data in my collectionView comes from a NSFetchResultController.

I'm pretty happy with how my UI works so if there is a simple way to NOT reload the section header, then that would be great!

Comment: This solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19990562/901334

Answer (score 35):

I finally figured this out after trying many different options. The solution is to make your header of its own section so you can reload the other sections independently without reloading the one your header is attached to.

So:

- Section 0

  - Header

    - Search bar (or other text fields)
  - Rows

    - (None)
- Section 1

  - Header

    - Create an empty UICollectionReusableView and override ...sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath to return CGSizeZero
  - Rows

    - Your actual rows that would have originally gone with section 0

Then, we you need to reload your data:

`[collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]];`

Your searchbar or text fields should retain their focus while the user is typing and you can update the results in the background.

Comment: This is the best way to implement a search bar or text input field inside your colletionView to filter your data source. Thanks

Comment: Now, this is most intelligent solution. Thank you sir.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a project that can demonstrate? I am at my eyeballs trying to get this to work. Especially since I am working with custom layout attributes for all my items and headers too. Each row of items are created in their own sections. So each section has 1 row. As a test, I delete 1 section for every character I type and there's no reload. So I figured I'd delete every section, and then insert the new sections instead but that causes a reload ! Perhaps you can take a look at the Filtering branch at http://github.com/pavankataria/SwiftDataTables ? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately this way it'll be impossible to keep the search bar at the top via `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds`

Comment: Smart! 
Just a small issue: A kind of blinking of cells is seen now. But not that important

Comment: This does not seem to be working with swift 4 xcode 9. Reload data still hides keyboard

Comment: That's overkill but sadly the only way to do it, thanks!

Comment: Fantastic answer! Works for Swift 5 in Aug 2020

Comment: It works, but it's slow to compare to reloadData.

Comment: Is there an example about how to make the search bar a separate section? Thank you!

Comment: To answer @TamásZahola's concern: To keep the search bar pinned to the top, instead of using a header from a different section, I used a "dummy" header, then pinned the real header to the dummy header's sides using constraints, then added the real header directly as a subview of the collection view. With this "hack" the real header wont resign first responder status

Answer (score 5):

did you tried with one of this options?

To reload just the new items

```
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

To reload the complete section

```
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
```

Or, if it doesn't work.. make searchBar  first responder again after your updates

```
    [self.collectionViewPackages performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    }];
```

Comment: Making the search bar first responder post reload actually only works in iOS7.0 but not iOS7.1 strangely enough.