# UISearchBar losing focus

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, first-responder

I have a UISearchBar for a UITableView and my implementation is as follows:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    if(searchText.length == 0)
    {
        self.isFiltered = NO;     
    }
    else
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.writer1 contains[c] %@", searchText];
        self.isFiltered = YES;
        [[RTRepairOrderStore sharedStore] filterROArray:predicate];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];    
}
```

The issue is that after I type one letter into the search bar, the search works but the keyboard is immediately dismissed. How can I prevent this?

Comment: here is the correct answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796944/4833705

Answer (score 9):

The searchBar is losing focus because it's likely located in the tableView header, and the tableView is being reloaded.

You can prevent this by either:

- Moving the searchBar so it's no longer a subView of the tableView.  Options include placing the searchBar in a navigation bar, or in a view above the tableView.
- Replacing `reloadData` with one of the following approaches to avoid reloading the tableView header:

  - Use `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` to reload a section of the table, or
  - Use `beginUpdates` `endUpdates` to animate changes for specific rows to be inserted or deleted.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is to make the becomeFirstResponder call to happen after the reloadData one:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

This is working on iOS 8.1.2, I didn't test it on other versions yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues encountered above but for a different reason.  My `UISearchBar` was within a cell at the top of the table.  When typing, I would call to reload the `UITableView` and this was causing the search bar to lose focus - because the cell containing the search bar was one that was being reloaded.

The solution was to only reload the cells I needed.  My search bar was in section 0, and all search results in section one. So a call like this ensured that only section 1 was reloaded, and the search bar did not lose focus.

```
NSIndexSet *section1 = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
[self.tableView reloadSections:section1 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Answer (score 0):

When `searchBar:textDidChange:` is called, `searchBar` **is** the `FirstResponder`. There is no need to send it a `becomeFirstResponder` message.
Moreover, you do send `becomeFirstResponder` to `self.searchBar`, which might not be the same as the `searchBar` that is transferred to you during the `searchBar:textDidChange:` method call.
I suggest to delete `[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];` and to check if your property `self.searchBar` is really linked to the `searchBar` object in the callback `searchBar:textDidChange:`.