# reloadData not calling cellForItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I followed [UICollectionView reloadData resigns first responder in section header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724198/uicollectionview-reloaddata-resigns-first-responder-in-section-header) to implement search bar on collectionview, but when `collectionView?.reloadData()` is called, the screen below is shown and i've to scroll down to find the filtered cells.
My code for datasource

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return section == 0 ? 0 : count // this got called after reloadData
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(...)
    // this function did not get called after reloadData
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the code of search bar part and reloadData .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem...I set my search bar height to `collectionView.contentSize`, which changed from 50 to 2600 after `reloadData` for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when your collectionview reload it has something to show.  Count has some value if you datasource has 0 value then also your cellForItem will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

How about you reload only the cells and not all data? After filtering the datasource array, you can compare `count` to `collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(1)` and based on that, you can reload the cells that you need, and delete the rest or add if you need more. A perk of doing it this way is that you can also get nice filtering animations.