# Prevent Search bar from resigning being first responder SWIFT 4.2

Tags: uisearchbar, collectionview, swift4.2, reloaddata, becomefirstresponder

I have a search bar in my collection view's header and I want to be able to filter the contents as user types. The problem is, every time i reload the collection view in textDidChange event of search bar, collection view becomes first responder and search bar resigns being, thus hiding keyboard.

I have checked all the answers in;

[UICollectionView reloadData resigns first responder in section header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724198/uicollectionview-reloaddata-resigns-first-responder-in-section-header)

[How to filter UICollectionView and keep keyboard up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255270/how-to-filter-uicollectionview-and-keep-keyboard-up/19990562#19990562)

And any other posts that could be related but had no luck finding an answer.
I'de be very happy if you guys can help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any proper solution for this issue so I've added my searchbar to my main view and synchronized its height value with my collection views didscroll event.

Here is the code snippet if anyone is interested.

```
    let offset = self.collectionView.contentOffset
    let y = offset.y

    if lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y && lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height {
        // move up
        if self.cst_searchBarHeight.constant == 0 && y <= 0{
            self.cst_searchBarHeight.constant = self.searchBarHeight
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }

    } else if lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        // move down
        if self.cst_searchBarHeight.constant != 0{
            self.cst_searchBarHeight.constant = 0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    // update the new position acquired
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

I've got the idea from the below answer which finds out the scroll direction of collection view
[How can I detect the scroll direction from the UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480436/how-can-i-detect-the-scroll-direction-from-the-uicollectionview)